# Get git status from remote repository

Tags: git

Assume I have 2 computers **A** and **B** on a network. Now from **A** I would like to be able to run a **git status** on a non-bare git repository on machine **B** to see if any changes has been made (including local changes not yet added).

To do that I would RDP or SSH to **B**, locate the repo and do a git status.

But are there better/automatic approaches for doing this? E.g. git hook that sends a mail each time a file is modified in the repo on machine **B**?

Comment: This smells like an X/Y problem. Are you looking for uncommitted work on a secondary desktop or laptop?

Comment: What do you mean by X/Y Problem? Yes I am looking for uncommitted work on a secondary computer/desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git hooks don't trigger on file changes, only on git commands. You could write git hook for e.g. pre-commit or post-commit, but not for file change (you would need some other tool e.g. `inotifywait` for that).

But if you have ssh access to machine, then it's not really that hard - you can do all that with single command:

```
ssh <host> "git -C <path to repo> status"
```

But it works with git newer than 1.8.5. In older versions you need to:

```
ssh <host> "cd <path to repo> && git status"
```

Remember to exchange keys between your local comp and remote host to avoid typing in password every time. You can also give short alias to remote hostname in ssh_config file. Then just place above line in separate script and it will save you a lot of typing ;)